# How to retain quotes when executing a command in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which contains something similar to the following:

```
cmd="grep 'a b'"

echo $cmd
$cmd
```

The issue I am having is that the $cmd, for some reason, removes the quotes around the 'a b', and executes the command as `grep a b`, causing it to error:

```
% ./test.sh
grep 'a b'
grep: b': No such file or directory
```

I have tried various combinations of quotes and escaping, but the result is always the same.

Comment: It's not executing `grep a b`; it executes `grep` with two arguments `'a` and `b'`. The single quotes are treated as literal characters after `$cmd` is evaluated, not quoting operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place to store commands is in functions. Rule of thumb: Variables are for data; functions are for commands.

```
cmd() {
    grep 'a b'
}

...

cmd
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use strings for that, but arrays:

```
cmd=( grep 'a b' )
"${cmd[@]}"
```

See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for in-depth overview.

Comment: This works for simple commands, but I still wouldn't recommend storing an entire command line in a single variable. Command name? Yes. Command options? Yes. Both together? [Use a function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27005048/1126841).